# Javascript location.replace not working

Tags: javascript, redirect

this problem has been seen many times in stackoverflow and there are many solutions to it, but setting it return false, using location.replace instead of location.href doesn't work out for me. Could you please help see what's the problem in my code:

```
"use strict";
var pass = document.getElementById("password").value, repass = document.getElementById("repassword").value;

if (pass !== repass) {
    window.alert("password does not match!");
    return true;
} else {     
    window.alert("Thank You,\nYou have successfully registered.");
    window.location.replace("Login.html");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you have `return` statements that are not in a function ... that's not valid

Comment: Why are the `return`'s there? This isn't in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do `window.location = '/Login.html'`